# Empty JSON data when function call, but logs data at console

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, function

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/knLhae13/10/) fiddle is not working

The problem is here I assume with the `getDATA` function.

```
var getDATA = function(arr) {
    var cb = '?client_id=c292fn290f4pac7cpk4j4t137uk3tn&callback=?';
    var url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/';
    var hardCodedJSON = [];
    arr.forEach(function(stream) {
        var obj = {};
        var newUrl = url + 'streams/' + stream + cb;
        $.getJSON(newUrl).success(function(data) {
            // console.log(data)
            var streaming = (data.stream === null) ? false : true;
            if (streaming) {
                obj.classes = 'success fa fa-thumbs-up';
            } else {
                obj.classes = 'danger fa fa-thumbs-down';
            }
            obj.username = stream;
            hardCodedJSON.push(data);
            console.log(hardCodedJSON);
        });
    });
    console.log(hardCodedJSON);
    return hardCodedJSON;

};
```

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/0vduzqvb/1/) fiddle is working with hardcoded data.
It is really killing me. The concept is so simple yet I'm not getting the data in the function. But when i console logs it out. The Data is there. I am making a very basic mistake. Please check it out.

Comment: Is that $.getJSON`` passing something to the ``.success(data)``?

Comment: are you able to `console.log(hardCodedJSON);` at both the places ?